# Error when trying to call a function from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view controllers and want to call a function from the first view controller in the second one.

This works:

```
class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController {

    func doSomething() {
        print("Did something")
    }

}

class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        let vcOne: ViewControllerOne = ViewControllerOne()
        vcOne.doSomething()
    }

}
```

But when I put `self.ScrollView.setContentOffset(...)` (`ScrollView` is an `IBOutlet` in `ViewControllerOne`) in the `doSomething()` function I get `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.` as soon as the function is called from `ViewControllerTwo`. Would be nice if someone could explain what I did wrong and maybe how to fix it.

Actual Code that is causing the error:

```
class PageContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    ...
    func setOffset() {
        self.ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    }
    ...
}

class ContactsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    ...
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selected = __contacts[indexPath.row]
        if !__chats.contains(selected) {
            __chats.append(selected)
            let pageContainer: PageContainerViewController = PageContainerViewController()
            pageContainer.setOffset()

        }

        activeChat = selected

        print(__chats)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi did you add the public reserved word to the func declaration?

Comment: Just tried, doesn't help.

Comment: Does the `view controller one` present before, and then it show `view controller 2`?

Comment: I use objective-C and not swift and but in this case I use the delegate. With the delegates you can execute code in a second viewcontroller from another view controller. I think toy can find example for swift

Comment: @t4nhpt `ViewControllerOne` has a ScrollView and `ViewControllerTwo` is a subview of that ScrollView. The problem is not calling a function from another view controller, it's that I get "unexpectedly found nil" when I access the ScrollView's setContentOffset in any way from another function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how you have to do it, based on this sample this is the way:

Code for the first `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
public class ViewController: UIViewController {

  public override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  public override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  public func DoSomething(parameter: String) ->String{
      return parameter
  }
  }
```

This is the code for the second `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labelParameter: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let controller: ViewController = ViewController()

        labelParameter.text = controller.DoSomething("Test")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

The storyboard I think is irrelevant but let me know if you need it; technically I have the first view controller with a button, the button has a segue the second view controller which calls the `DoSomething` method from the first `ViewController`.

I hope this is the idea that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but calling the function wasn't a problem, just accessing the scrollView in the function that's being called gave me an error.

Comment: Edited my post to include the code that's causing the error.